# I am getting a error using urllib and bs4 "http.client.BadStatusLine:"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this file called 'recognized.txt' which has some text like this

Link to the recognized.txt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yCQz6cQPDmcCOuXBOCAX4nvNoUqewE0y/view?usp=sharing

:[image]

My code:-

```
f = open('recognized.txt','r')
message = f.read()
message.replace(" ", "")
print(message)
f.close()


import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
url = ('https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q='+message)                                                              # no javascript



sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
a = soup.body.b
print(a)

for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='result__snippet'):
    print(i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
```

So when i run the above code it gives me an error as:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ocr\webparse.py", line 26, in <module>
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1321, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

1. What does the error mean?
2. Why am i getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code with your txt-file I managed to replicate the issue. This is what I did:

- Removed all the newlines from your message and spaces with strip()
- removed 'lxml' from BeautifulSoup()

This seems to produce a decent result.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

with open('Downloads/recognized.txt') as f:
    message = f.read().strip()

url = ('https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q='+message)

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce)
a = soup.body.b
print(a)

for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='result__snippet'):
    print(i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
```

The printout look like so:

```
<b>Dinosaur</b>
Dinosaurs - are a diverse group of reptiles of the clade Dinosauria. They first appeared during the Triassic period, between 243 and 233.23 million years ago...
 - Dinosaur - . Quite the same Wikipedia. Just better. - Dinosaur - . From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.
Мультфильм, триллер, приключения. Режиссер: Эрик Лейтон, Ральф Зондаг. В ролях: Элфри Вудард, Осси Дэвис, Макс Казелла и др. Путешествие трехтонного игуанодонта по имени Аладар...
Перевод слова - dinosaur - , американское и британское произношение, транскрипция, словосочетания, примеры использования.
```

The problem seem to be with your message variable.  I cleaned it up so it's a simple string without newlines.  Now it works fine.

Comment: Yeah i added the link in my question, you can check it out

Comment: I adjusted the code with your new message format.  Essentially your message-string wasn't cleaned properly.